# Android databinding with Kotlin map

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

This is a **basic** question that for some reason Google doesn't seem to have the answer. I'm trying to use a Kotlin map object with databinding for xml. How the heck do I import the Map object in the xml?
Using

```
            name="formIds"
            type="kotlin.collections.MapsKt" />
```

doesn't import the map object. I get a `Failed to resolve Bracked Expr formIds["Submit"], target: kotlin.collections.MapsKt` when I try to use the object.

I create formIds as follows:

```
val _formIds =
        mapOf<FormType, Map<String, Int>>(...
```

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type="kotlin.collections.MapsKt"` is not enought for databinding. Declare it explictly with types and provide import if required. For example `type="java.util.HashMap&lt;String, Integer&gt;"`